# NuxtJS + Vuex — datas in the store

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex, nuxt.js

Using [NuxtJS](https://nuxtjs.org/) (a VueJS framework), I’m trying to get a bunch of datas from a REST API in a layout template (which can’t use the classic fech() or asyncData() methods).

So I'm using [vuex](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store) and the [nuxtServerInit()](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#the-nuxtserverinit-action) action.
This way, I should be able to gather all the datas directly during the load of the app, regardless of the current page.

But I can’t get it to work.

Here’s my map.js file for the store:

```js
import axios from 'axios'

const api = 'http://rest.api.localhost/spots'
 
export const state = () => ({
 markers: null
})

export const mutations = {
 init (state) {
  axios.get(api)
   .then((res) => {
    state.markers = res.data
   })
 }
}

export const actions = {
 init ({ commit }) {
  commit('init')
 }
}
```

And the index.js (that can fire the nuxtServerInit()):

```js
export const state = () => {}

export const mutations = {}

export const actions = {
 nuxtServerInit ({ commit }) {
  // ??
  console.log('test')
 }
}
```

But I can’t get it to work. The doc says:

> If you are using the Modules mode of the Vuex store, only the primary module (in store/index.js) will receive this action. You'll need to chain your module actions from there.

But I don’t know how I shall do this. How do I call an action defined in another module/file?

I tried to copy various example, but never got them to work ; this is the best I could come up with.

What did I missed? If needed, here’s the [repo](https://github.com/EmmanuelBeziat/parkourfinder) and the [store folder](https://github.com/EmmanuelBeziat/parkourfinder/tree/master/store)

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ran into the same problem, a few weeks ago, and here is how I solved it:
**======== CLASSIC MODE =========**
**store/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import auth from './modules/auth'
import auth from './modules/base'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default () => {
  return new Vuex.Store({
    actions: {
      nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { req }) {
        if (req.session.user && req.session.token) {
          commit('auth/SET_USER', req.session.user)
          commit('auth/SET_TOKEN', req.session.token)
        }
      }
    },
    modules: {
      auth,
      base
    }
  })
}
```

**store/modules/auth.js**

```
const state = () => ({
  user: null,
  token: null
})

const getters = {
  getToken (state) {
    return state.token
  },
  getUser (state) {
    return state.user
  }
}

const mutations = {
  SET_USER (state, user) {
    state.user = user
  },
  SET_TOKEN (state, token) {
    state.token = token
  }
}

const actions = {
  async register ({ commit }, { name, slug, email, password }) {
    try {
      const { data } = await this.$axios.post('/users', { name, slug, email, password })
      commit('SET_USER', data)
    } catch (err) {
      commit('base/SET_ERROR', err.response.data.message, { root: true })
      throw err
    }
  },
  /* ... */
}

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions
}
```

---

Please notice the lines `commit('base/SET_ERROR', err.response.data.message, { root: true })`, which calls the mutation in another module (called base). And the `namespaced: true` option, which is required for this to work.
To learn more about namespacing in vuex modules, please refer to the documentation: https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/modules.html

---

**======== MODULES MODE =========**
The new 'modules mode' makes this much easier. You can have all the files in one folder and 'namespaced = true' is not required anymore.
Here is how the above files look in modules mode:

**store/index.js**

```
export const state = () => ({})

export const actions = {
  async nuxtServerInit ({ commit }, { req }) {
    if (req.session.user && req.session.token) {
      commit('auth/SET_USER', req.session.user)
      commit('auth/SET_TOKEN', req.session.token)
    }
  }
}
```

**store/auth.js**

```
const state = () => ({
  user: null,
  token: null
})

const getters = {
  getUser (state) {
    return state.user
  },
  getToken (state) {
    return state.token
  }
}

const mutations = {
  SET_USER (state, user) {
    state.user = user
  },
  SET_TOKEN (state, token) {
    state.token = token
  }
}

const actions = {
  async register ({ commit }, { name, slug, email, password }) {
    try {
      const { data } = await this.$axios.post('/users', { name, slug, email, password })
      commit('SET_USER', data)
    } catch (err) {
      commit('base/SET_ERROR', err.response.data.message, { root: true })
      throw err
    }
  }
}

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  mutations,
  actions
}
```

---

To learn more about modules mode in nuxtjs, please refer to the documentation:
https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/#modules-mode

Comment: it is deprecated in nuxt 2, and will be removed in nuxt 3, what is the new way to implement this?